# How to get value of checkbox in ul li

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of checkbox and one button search.how can i get the value of checkbox was checked and push in to array to call ajax when i click in button search.

```
<ul class="sb_dropdown" style="display:none;">
                    <li class="sb_filter">Chon the loai</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"/><label for="all"><strong>Tất cả</strong></label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"/><label for="Automotive">Đồ nữ</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"/><label for="Baby">Giày</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"/><label for="Beauty">Túi sách</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"/><label for="Books">Đồ nam</label></li>                      
                </ul>

<input class="sb_search" type="submit" value=""/>
```

this is my jquery

```
<script>
                        $('.sb_search').click(function () {
                            var list = [];
                            $('ul.sb_dropdown').find("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function () {
                                list.push($(this).val());
                            });

                     });
                    </script>
```

Comment: Please show your current jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('ul.sb_dropdown').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function ()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

- Your checkboxes do not have a `value`, hence pushing `$(this).val()` into an array will push the default `on`.
- Your `filter` fails to use the correct syntax.

```js
$('.sb_search').click(function () {
    var list = [];
    $('ul.sb_dropdown').find("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        list.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#output').html(list.join(", "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sb_dropdown">
    <li class="sb_filter">Chon the loai</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Tất cả"/><label for="all"><strong>Tất cả</strong></label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Đồ nữ"/><label for="Automotive">Đồ nữ</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Giày"/><label for="Baby">Giày</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Túi sách"/><label for="Beauty">Túi sách</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Đồ nam"/><label for="Books">Đồ nam</label></li>                      
</ul>

<input class="sb_search" type="submit" value=""/>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @jamiec when i alert list ,i show me default on,i dont want to show in html,i want the list to do ajax,by the way why i click button this page refeshed.

Comment: @CongHS - The outputting to html was just to demonstrate, the variable `list` just contains an array of values as per your original.